# Calculation of volume integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate
$$\int_0^h \int_0^R\int_0^{\sqrt {R^2-y^2}}x^2\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\ ?$$

I got
$$\int_0^h\int_0^R\frac{(R^2-y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz$$

Then I don't know how to proceed...

I have thought about change of variables to $R\sin\theta$, but I don't get any good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^R\frac{(R^2-y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\mathrm dy&=R\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(R^2-R^2\cos^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\sin \theta \mathrm d\theta\\
&=\frac{R^4}{3}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^4 \mathrm d\theta\\
&=\frac{R^4}{3}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\frac38-\frac14\cos 2\theta+\frac18 \cos4\theta)\mathrm d\theta\\
&=\frac{R^4}{3}\times \frac{3\pi}{16}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

For the second integral you obtained, do try the following change of variables.

$$y=R\sin\theta$$
$$z=R\cos\theta$$
$$dA=rdrd\theta$$

You will be able to integrate if you do that.